# How to write with respect about saying that original work is done by someone else?

Tags: sentence-meaning, phrases, sentence-choice

I used a Mirza Ghalib Urdu poetry to create almost similar poetry (the pink image contains the poetry I created in *Hinglish* language. It's just a rough illustration to represent the poetry I created.) of 2 lines which emphasizes that I'm failing continuously at getting job because of hard time. *(In case of actual poetry, it as about failure of love. I replaced love with job stuff)*.

Now, I don't want to disrespect Mirza Ghalib at all. So with the design I want to share (the 2nd line in caption in the image below in black text) that it is totally inspired from his poetry and doesn't mean to disrespect him.

Also, the text you would suggest here has come to after a caption, in following way:

[image]

Summary: I don't need writing for a poetry. I need a better sentence **(pointed by yellow arrow)** to show some respect to Mirza Ghalib and admit that my design is inspired from his poetry.

How should I write that?

Comment: There's a pretty standard construction exemplified for your context by something like *Writing job application resumés in times of high unemployment is like flogging a dead horse - **it's a lot of effort for little reward.*** Where that final highlighted "explanation" element is usually omitted if the way in which the two things are similar is obvious (as with my example), but in other cases it's some non-obvious / ***amusing*** way of drawing a comparison: *Love is like a good cigar: it can go out many times, but each time you relight it, it tastes worse.* But this is Off Topic writing advice

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's non-specific  "writing advice"

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica I think you misunderstood my question and details.

Comment: I admit I have no idea exactly what you're asking here. You English isn't really good enough for you to clarify what kind of help you're looking for here, let alone write English *poetry* (which would normally require much greater fluency than simply asking questions). I just pointed out an "idiomatically standard" construction often used for making comparisons. Other possibilities include *To paraphrase Mirza Ghalib...* or (most modestly) *With apologies to Mirza Ghalib...* followed by your own text ***in the style of*** Mirza Ghalib.

Comment: Unfortunately you misunderstood my question :( Let me edit the details better.

Comment: Please do that! :)

Comment: Does it make sense to you now?

Comment: I'm afraid not. Did you *intend* to just have a meaningless coloured block under **(I don't want to disrespect Mirza Ghalib text)** in that graphic you included? But to repeat my earlier suggestion, maybe what you want here is **With apologies to Mirza Ghalib** as an alternative to that highlighted text. It's a common self-deprecating way of admitting that  you know your efforts will look feeble compared to some well-known great  writer/poet, but that you're at least *trying* to emulate the style.

Comment: OMG. Please check edit.

Comment: Okay, I retract my closevote. It seems likely to me that just about the *only* text that would suit the context is exactly the one I've now repeated twice in comments. You might use ***To paraphrase Mirza Ghalib*** if the exact text of your alternative is extremely similar to some well-known line(s) by "the master", but that version doesn't inherently imply "modesty" or even "respect" in the same way. Note that **Looking for job in hard time** is completely non-idiomatic / ungrammatical in English (even in a *poetic* context, where unusual syntax is often acceptable).

Comment: I find your English too hard to understand :(

Comment: The feeling is mutual - I find *your* English hard to understand! :)

Comment: Sure, I'll fix the first line (looking one). Priority is 2nd line.

Comment: Okay. Let me say it better: I find your English too proficient to understand for me.

Comment: With apologies to Mirza Ghalib is respectful?

Comment: Enough already! I've formally posted "the answer"! If that doesn't work for you then I'm stumped! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A standard turn of phrase (idiomatic usage) for the context here is...

> ***With apologies to Mirza Ghalib...***
>    (Your poetic efforts, which you admit are feeble compared to one of the acknowledged "poetic greats")

This is a common self-deprecating way of admitting that you know your "poetry" isn't particularly good by comparison - but at least you're *trying* to emulate the style.

Comment: Do I have to write just "With apologies to Mirza Ghalib" or also the 2nd line you've quoted under it?

Comment: I think you should forget about trying to write poetry in a language you don't yet understand very well. Concentrate on learning more of the basics.

Comment: No. no. I completely understand the poetry, that's why edited it to my version. I just replaced 2 words and it perfectly makes sense. The poetry is not in English, it is in Urdu which is very similar to Hindi. Hindi is main language here.

Comment: Well, I guess it's up to you. But honestly, you have a ***lot*** to learn about English, and I don't see how this sort of question is going to help you do that. Nor am I sure this specific question will ever be any use to *other* learners, and the whole *point* of ELL (and *all* SO sites) is that questions and answers should become a useful reference source for ***future*** visitors.

Comment: Why I asked this because it's not limited to this question. I face similar problem on many instances. When I share others' stuff I don't have the right words. For example sometimes I use phrase "credit to him" or "posted by him" or something like that. You see I'm not confident here. I'm not sure if it's grammatically correct or not. I have the feelings to express, but don't know how to put it into words. I'm not sure if it is credit or credits etc.

Comment: But that's precisely my point! If you have difficulty putting your *question* here into words (so I could easily understand what you're looking for help with), you're probably not yet ready to tackle writing *poetry*. Note that because I don't understand Urdu (and I'm not sure what you mean by "Hinglish"), *and* because you don't seem to have set out either the "original" text from Mirza Ghalib OR your own text inspired by it, it's still not clear to me exactly what the relationship between the two texts is.

Comment: (It might make a difference whether you're simply imitating the general style, or *specifically* reproducing a well-known quote with slight modification.)

Comment: I honestly wonder why you feel I have not understood the poetry. And the question was far less about poetry than a separate sentence suggestion.

BTW I'll explain the actual poetry in English: "Before the postman comes (with a response), I must write another same letter again because I know what the response would be (from the person I love)".

My edit: "Before the email comes (with a response), I must write another resume again because I know what the response would be (from the recruiter. Intending he will reject my request)".

Comment: I'm certainly not saying you don't understand the poem written in in Urdu that you wish to emulate. I'm not even suggesting you couldn't "understand" at least *some* poetry written in English (but the purpose of poetry is often simply to induce certain *feelings* in the reader; that can be done even if a poem includes words or syntax the reader has never seen before). All I'm saying is I don't think it's really possible to *write* poetry in a language you don't know very well.

Comment: Correct! But I did write that *poetry* in Hindi (Very similar to Urdu), not in English. Only the caption is in English. I hope it clear things now.

Comment: Oh. I *didn't* realise that your context here involved lines of poetry that you have written *in Hindi*. In which case I still don't really understand why you would want to "introduce" your poetic efforts in *English*, but obviously some of my comments above are irrelevant. Note that my suggested *With apologies to Mirza Ghalib* isn't an actual "English sentence" - it's just an adverbial phrase used to introduce whatever text follows. As is another alternative - ***After the style of**  Mirza Ghalib...* (but that one doesn't include any "respectful / modest" implications) .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/102955/discussion-between-vikas-and-fumblefingers-reinstate-monica).